# unable to persist postgresql data using named volume in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am using `docker-compose` to spin up a `spring` api with a `postgres` database . I am new to `docker` and I am trying to persist my database using a named volume I created with

```
docker volume create employeedata
```

I add this volume inside my `docker-compose.yml` but the db does not persist if I stop or remove my containers .

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    container_name: springboot-postgresql
    image: springboot-postgresql
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgresqldb
  postgresqldb:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - employeedata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=employeedb
volumes:
  employeedata:
```

I tried doing `docker inspect employeedata` and got the result below

[image]

It seems fishy to me that the `docker-compose` version is 2 and not 3 plus I don't understand how the mountpoint is related to the volume path I specify in my `docker-compose.yml` above

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker compose created all objects in a project namespace. This namespace is usually the folder name of the docker-compose.yml file but you can set it by passing --project-name to (all) your calls to docker compose.

As docker does not have first class namespaces, the project name is simply used as a prefix for all objects defined in the compose file, so in this case, assuming your project was in a folder called "project" then compose would have created `project_app` as the container and `project_employeedata` as the volume.

To override this, you specify an explict `container-name` as you have done. But you really shouldn't as it means that any two deployments of compose files with this name will now conflict.

And to override it for volumes - tell docker compose that the volume is externally created and provide the external name. Otherwise compose will try to use the namespaced name.

```yaml
volumes:
  employeedata:
    external: true
    name: employeedata
```

Again, letting compose manage the volume name is probably the better option. Simply ensure the directory hosting the compose file has a unique name that is suitable - or ensure a suitable unique name is passed via --project-name, and then manage the volume using `whatever_employeedata`.

nb. Docker compose does not remove compose managed volumes unless -v / --volumes is passed to `docker compose down` so your data will persist here.

`/var/lib/docker/volumes` is simply the (default) location that docker will manage volumes.

The 2.0 refers to the version of compose, not the version in your compose.yml file.

Comment: I tried using anonymous volumes but still the data does not persist after I do docker-compose stop and then docker-compose up again